# VScode define custom shortcut for restart and run all

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have been using VS Code for my notebooks recently. However, I really miss the "restart and run all" shortcut offered in the vanilla Jupyter notebook. I found the restart option in the setting.
[image]
I also found the run-all option.
[image]
Is there a way that I can combine these two triggers into one?

Comment: This question exists as a github issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9242).

Answer (score 8):

**2023 update**: In the current version of VSCode, **this is really easy.**

1. Open your Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Search for "Restart Kernel". This gives you two results:[image]
3. Set the keybinding for "Notebook: Restart Kernel". In vanilla Jupyter Notebook it is `0 0`, but that won't work in VSCode (you won't be able to write 0 in your code basically). I use `ctrl+shift+0` but it's up to you.

You may need to reload windows (or close and open the app) for this to work.

Answer (score 6):

There is a vscode extension called [`multi-command`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) that allows you to do that. Go to your extensions, find the extension and install it. After you do that go to your keybinds and open the `keybindings.json`, you can do so by clicking here (pic attached).

[image: here]

Then go ahead and add the following:

```json
{
  "key": "oem_8",                            //put whatever key you want here
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [                            //put whatever keybind actions you want in here
      "jupyter.notebookeditor.restartkernel",
      "notebook.execute"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: You definitely Helped! Thanks!

Comment: I had a bit of trouble finding the `keybindings.json` file. After some googling, I found you can find the `keybindings.json` file by:  

1. Opening the Keyboard Shortcuts editor: File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts on macOS)
2. Selecting the Open Keyboard Shortcuts button on the right of the editor title bar. (This is the button pictured above.)
This will open your keybindings.json file for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

VSCode's Jupyter extension now has a "Jupyter: Restart Kernel and Run All Cells" command (`jupyter.restartkernelandrunallcells`).[[1]](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/pull/13316) You can map this freely in the keyboard shortcuts.